# Send an email when a custom record is created via a sublist

Tags: netsuite

I have a sublist on my sales order form that allows the user to add a custom record directly from the sales order.

What I would like to do is have an e-mail sent when that custom record is created but it is not working when the record is created via the sublist - only when created from the custom record form.

Is it possible to send an email when the record is created via the sublist?

Comment: What code are you running to respond to creation via form?

Answer (score 0):

The event of create from a sublist is not catch by an UserEvent. You can create a ClientScript, capture the event sublistChanged(context) and then call a suitelet to send the email from the backend.

```js
define(['N/runtime', 'N/url', 'N/https'],
    function(runtime, url, https){
    
    function sublistChanged(context) {
    
        try {               

            console.log('Debug: ', '* * * S t a r t * * *'); 

            var suiteUrl = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: 'customscript_xxxxx_xxxxxxx',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_xxxxx_xxxxxxx',
                returnExternalUrl: false,
                params: {
                        custparam_custid : intCustId,
                        custparam_authorid: userObjId
                        
                    }
            });

            var response = https.get({
                                url: suiteUrl
                            });
                
            }catch (error) {
                console.log('error: ', error);                
            }
    }
    
    return {
            sublistChanged: sublistChanged
        }
});
```